# how to identify a " 's "in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am wondering how can I identify a `'s`(e.g., Linda's, organization's) in a sentence in Python?

For example:
`if xx == "'s":` ,  `if xx == "\'s":`  `if xx == "'\s":` are not correct, does anyone how exactly should I write this?

Note: `Linda's` is divided into `Linda` and `'s`  in my code, that's why I have to use a judgement sentence.

Comment: ```if "'s" in xx:``` will work (if xx is the string that contains 's)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do and how you've tried to achieve it, and add a minimal working example of the problem.

Comment: My two cents: There are a lot of different characters that *look* like `'` on your keyboard but are actually a different unicode character. Happens a lot when parsing raw text from the web. Copy and paste that `'s` from the sentence into your code and see if it matches.

Comment: @Winter Squad, thanks, but I have just tried, it does not work. Don't I need to use a '\' in front of the ' 's ', I have checked the usage of '\', it does not have this function, but the directly usage of ''s' is not working:)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Johannes Gontrum, this is exactly the point, it works, I just copied the 's from my text directly, then it works, also thanks  Winter Squad

Comment: @Melina, if your string contains an inner single quote ('), just use double quote (") delimiter, then you don't need escape the character. By my self convention I use double quotes for sentences (and long strings, that might contains single quotes) and single quote for keys in dictionaries. In Python, string delimiters have no different use, like in other languages (C#, C, C++, Java, Kotlin, C/AL, etc.)